# How do I join a new dock to an existing dock?

Tags: openttd

I have an existing dock. I am trying to build a new dock on the empty tile right next to the existing dock. I want the new dock to be joined to the existing dock, to increase the coverage area of the station.

[image: OpenTTD dock]

However, when I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> click to place the new dock on the empty tile, and select to join the new dock to the existing dock, this error message appears:

> Can't build dock here... Too close to another dock.

[image: OpenTTD error message: Can't build dock here...]

What did I do wrong? Is it even possible to join two docks together?

OpenTTD version: 1.9.3

Comment: Afaik the only way to expand is to demolish the existing one and immediately rebuild the bigger one. Do on beforehand make sure your [local authority rating](https://wiki.openttd.org/en/Manual/Game%20Mechanics/#local-authority-rating) is high enough to do so.

Comment: @MiG Is it even possible to build a bigger dock? I only see one size.

Comment: I'm not sure actually... I prefer to play trains and planes over boats so I rarely if ever have a water based congestion problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't join docks.  A given station [can only have one dock and one airport](https://wiki.openttd.org/en/Manual/Stations#combining-stations) as part of it; if you want to increase the coverage area, you need to add other station types.